# Integrate Django with VueJs

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

How to Integrate Django with VueJs?
What is the Standard way to integrate Django and VueJs? 
can anyone provide project structure and reference to learn

Comment: The same way you integrate Vue with any other framework. There's nothing Django-specific about it.

Comment: Django is for backend and Vuejs is for front end. Why would you integrate the two?

Answer (score 5):

1. Develop Django project with REST API that frontend applications can consume.
2. Develop Vue.js frontend application, which consume the REST API you
   developed with Django

Answer (score 3):

vuejs is a framework for front end and it has virtual environment it self.

maybe you're assuming like django templating in jinja but you're wrong

first of all develop a application written in vuejs as front end

second develop a application written in django as back end

and lastly connect them together using api in vuejs like axios

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios

Answer (score 2):

I have a boilerplate template to start. https://github.com/haseebeqx/django-vue-minimal/

but it can be easily achieved by editing STATICFILES_DIRS and TEMPLATES['DIRS'] in`settings.py`. and keeping all assets in vuejs. so that django is used for sending contents only as an api and vue.js will handle all frontend logic.